# artificial boundary condition

Tags: tikz-pgf

It is a target figure.
[image]

The output of my code is[image]
unfortunately, I cannot fill the right side. Please help me.

```
\documentclass{article}‎
‎\usepackage{tikz}‎‎
‎\begin{document}‎
‎\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]‎‎
‎\fill[blue!‎1‎5‎!white] (‎-5‎,‎4‎) rectangle (‎-1.5‎,‎0‎)‎;‎‎
‎\draw ‎[‎thick, ‎gray,‎‎‎‎‎->] (-5,0)--(‎4‎,0) node[right‎, ‎below] {$x$};‎
‎\draw ‎[‎thick,‎‎gray,‎->] (0,0)--(0,4) node[above‎, ‎left] {$y$};‎‎
‎\draw ‎[‎very ‎‎thick,‎red‎‎] (‎-‎1.5‎‎,0)--(‎-1‎.5‎‎,4)‎‎ node[above‎, ‎above‎] {$‎TBC‎$};‎‎
‎‎‎‎\draw[color=‎p‎urple‎!‎6‎‎‎0‎‎,‎smooth‎,‎very ‎thick‎, domain=‎0‎‎‎‎‎:‎1.9‎8‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎] plot (\x, ‎{‎‎\x*\x‎‎‎})‎;‎‎
‎\node[] at (‎-1.5‎,-0.15) {$‎a‎$};‎‎
‎\node[] at (‎-‎5‎‎,-0.15) {$‎-‎\infty‎‎‎$};‎‎
‎\node[] at (‎-‎5‎.2‎‎‎,‎4‎) {$‎\tau$‎};‎‎‎‎
‎\node[] at (‎-1.‎2‎‎,‎2‎.1‎‎) {$‎\Gamma_a‎‎$};‎‎
‎\node[] at (‎1.‎1‎‎‎,‎2‎.1‎‎) {$‎x_f(\tau)‎‎‎$};‎‎
‎\node[] at (‎0.‎2‎‎‎‎‎,‎-0.15‎‎‎) {$‎x_f(‎0‎)‎=0‎$};‎‎
‎\node[] at (‎-‎3‎‎‎,‎2‎) {$‎\Omega‎_‎e‎‎‎‎$};‎‎
‎\end{tikzpicture}‎
```

‎    \end{document}

Comment: Use pgfplots instead of straight tikz, then look up fillbetween, it's a library for pgfplots (afair), which Ca do exactly what your after, color between the functions xf and y=0

Answer (score 2):

I take that you do not want to use pgfplots nor its `fillbetween` library. Your problem is simple enough so that one can do without using these. If you have more complicated plots, I'd recommend to use those (or, at least, `fillbetween`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\fill[blue!15!white] (-5,4) rectangle (-1.5,0);
\draw [thick, gray,->] (-5,0)--(4,0) node[right, below] {$x$};
\draw [thick,gray,->] (0,0)--(0,4) node[above, left] {$y$};
\draw [very thick,red] (-1.5,0)--(-1.5,4) node[above, above] {$TBC$};
\draw[color=purple!60,smooth,very thick, domain=0:1.98] plot (\x, {\x*\x});
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\path[fill=purple!30] plot[smooth,domain=0:1.98] (\x, {\x*\x}) coordinate (aux)
-- (4,0 |-aux)|- (0,0);
\end{scope}
\node[] at (-1.5,-0.15) {$a$};
\node[] at (-5,-0.15) {$-\infty$};
\node[] at (-5.2,4) {$\tau$};
\node[] at (-1.2,2.1) {$\Gamma_a$};
\node[] at (1.1,2.1) {$x_f(\tau)$};
\node[] at (0.2,-0.15) {$x_f(0)=0$};
\node[] at (-3,2) {$\Omega_e$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think this type of diagram is easier in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) where you can deal with paths as variables, and create the shapes you want to fill without clipping or scopes etc, but that's probably just because I don't know TikZ very well!

Here's my effort, for what it's worth.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    numeric u;
    u = 2cm;

    path xx, yy, ff;

    xx = (5 left -- 4 right) scaled u;
    yy = (origin -- 4 up) scaled u;

    numeric s; s = 1/4;
    ff = (origin for x=s step s until 2: .. (x, x*x) endfor) scaled u;

    numeric a;
    a = -1;

    path exterior, interior, external;

    exterior = point 0 of xx -- (a*u,0) -- (a*u, ypart point infinity of yy) -- (xpart point 0 of xx, ypart point infinity of yy) -- cycle;
    interior = (a*u,0) -- ff -- (a*u, ypart point infinity of yy) -- cycle;
    external = origin -- point infinity of xx -- (xpart point infinity of xx, ypart point infinity of yy) -- reverse ff -- cycle;

    fill exterior withcolor 7/8[blue, white];
    fill interior withcolor 15/16 white;
    fill external withcolor 7/8[red + 1/2 green, white];

    draw ff withcolor 1/3 [red, blue];
    draw subpath (1, 2) of exterior withcolor 2/3 red;

    drawarrow xx;
    drawarrow yy;

    label.bot("$x$", point infinity of xx);
    label.bot("$-\infty$", point 0 of xx);
    label.top("$\tau$", point infinity of yy);

    label.rt("$\Gamma_a$", point 3/2 of exterior);
    label.ulft("$x_f(\tau)$", point 6 of ff);

    label("$\Omega_e = \hbox{Exterior Domain}$", center exterior);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```